# java - ERROR converting from byte[] to File (hex values)

Tags: java, file, hex, arrays

Okay guys, I have a file with some HEX values as well as a program that take this values with a byte[] in order to convert some hex values and then reconvert it to a file.
The problem is that when I reconvert de byte array to a file some hex values are modified, and I don't find the problem.
If you see any possible mistake don't hesitate.

As you can see I have a test.sav file, here it is:
[image]

And this is the product of the program, the two files are different and they should be the same because any change has been made:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {

public static File file;
public static String hex;
public static byte[] mext;
public static byte[] bytearray;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    file = new File("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Desktop\\test.sav");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    FileInputStream fin = null;

    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        bytearray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fin.read(bytearray);

        for(byte bytev : bytearray){ 
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", bytev));
        }
        System.out.println(sb);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {}

    //replaceMax(); <-- I deduced that conversion is not the problem 
    save(); // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART

}


public static void save() throws IOException{
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Desktop\\test2.sav");
    pw.write("");
    pw.close();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Desktop\\test2.sav"));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    out.write(new String(bytearray, "ASCII"));
    out.close();
}

}
```

Comment: You are not using `FileInputStream.read` correctly.  It might not return you all of the data in case I/O blocks.  Check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29).

Comment: How can I correct the I/O blocks, or just avoid them?

Comment: You should check the return value of `read` and if it is less than `bytarray.length`, call `read` again for the remaining bytes until finally the entire array is eventually read.  You'll want to switch to using the overload of `read` that accepts an offset as additional parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading data from a **binary** file and then trying to write it out as a **character** stream. Furthermore you're forcing it to use `ASCII` (a 7 bit character set) as the character encoding.

Try altering the `save` method to use:

```
     FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Roman\\Desktop\\test2.sav");
     try {
         output.write(bytearray);
     } finally {
         output.close();
     }
```

This will avoid character (re)encoding issues.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it this afternoon, if it works I'll set your answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Which Charset should I use? Can you explain the 7 bit characteristic of ASCII charset?

Comment: Steve's solution doesn't use any character set at all which is what you want.  Instead, the bytes are treated as, well, bytes.  Remember that there are only 2^7 = 128 ASCII characters defined but a byte can take on 2^8 = 256 different values so you cannot decode arbitrary byte arrays into sequences of ASCII characters in general.